# How to display Due, Over Due and Not Due based on a date field in Saved Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

For example I have a date field `delivery_datetime` in Index, I have to show the user for the current day whether a particular parcel is Due today or Over Due or Not Due

I can't create a separate field and do reindex because it's based on current date and that changes every day, for instance if I have to calculate while indexing I have to reindex every day, and that's not feasible because I have a lot of data.

I may use update by query but my index is frequently updated via a Python script, thought we don't have ACID property here we'll have version conflict.

For my knowledge I think my only option is to use Scripted Field.

If I have to write the logic in pseudocode:

```
Due - delivery_datetime.dateOnly == now.dateOnly
Over Due - delivery_datetime.dateOnly < now.dateOnly
Not Due - delivery_datetime.dateOnly > now.dateOnly
```

Thought I have a lot of data if I generate CSV I don't want scripted field to make major impact on cluster performance.

So I need some help to do this efficiently in scripted field, or if there were any completely different solution will also be greatly helpful.

Expecting help by providing painless script if Scripted Field is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, here is what worked for me.

**Scripted Field Script:**

```
def DiffMillis = 0;
if(!doc['delivery_datetime'].empty) {
    // Converting each to days, 1000*60*60*24 = 86400000
    DiffMillis = (new Date().getTime() / 86400000) - (doc['delivery_datetime'].value.getMillis() / 86400000);
}
doc['delivery_datetime'].empty ? "No Due Date": (DiffMillis==0?"Due": (DiffMillis>0?"Over Due":"Not Due") )
```

I specifically used *ternary operator*, because if I use `if else` then I have to use `return`, if I use `return` I faced `search_phase_execution_exception` while adding filters for the scripted field.

Answer (score 1):

Once we've ruled out doc upserts/updates there are essentially 2 approaches to this: `script_fields` or `filter aggregations`.

Let's first assume your mapping looks similar to:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "delivery_datetime": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "dateOnly": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dd.MM.yyyy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if we filter all our packages by, say, its ID and want to know in which due-state it is, we can create 3 script fields like so:

```
GET parcels/_search
{
  "_source": "timeframe_*",
  "script_fields": {
    "timeframe_due": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['delivery_datetime.dateOnly'].value.dayOfMonth == params.nowDayOfMonth",
        "params": {
          "nowDayOfMonth": 8
        }
      }
    },
    "timeframe_overdue": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['delivery_datetime.dateOnly'].value.dayOfMonth < params.nowDayOfMonth",
        "params": {
          "nowDayOfMonth": 8
        }
      }
    },
    "timeframe_not_due": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['delivery_datetime.dateOnly'].value.dayOfMonth > params.nowDayOfMonth",
        "params": {
          "nowDayOfMonth": 8
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which'll return something along the lines of:

```
...
"fields" : {
  "timeframe_due" : [
    true
  ],
  "timeframe_not_due" : [
    false
  ],
  "timeframe_overdue" : [
    false
  ]
}
```

*It's trivial and the date math has a significant weak point that'll be addressed below.*

Alternatively, we can use 3 filter aggregations and similarly filter only 1 document in question out like so:

```
GET parcels/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        "my_id_thats_due_today"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "due": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "delivery_datetime.dateOnly": {
            "gte": "now/d",
            "lte": "now/d"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "overdue": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "delivery_datetime.dateOnly": {
            "lt": "now/d"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "not_due": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "delivery_datetime.dateOnly": {
            "gt": "now/d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
...
"aggregations" : {
  "overdue" : {
    "doc_count" : 0
  },
  "due" : {
    "doc_count" : 1
  },
  "not_due" : {
    "doc_count" : 0
  }
}
```

Now the advantages of the 2nd approach are as follows:

1. There are no scripts involved -> faster execution.
2. More importantly, you don't have to worry about day-of-month math like Dec 15th being later than Nov 20th but the trivial day-of-month comparison would yield otherwise. You can implement something similar in your scripts but more complexity equals worse execution speed.
3. You can ditch the ID filtering and use those aggregated counts in an internal dashboard. Possibly even a customer dashboard but regular customers rarely have lots of parcels which would be reasonable to aggregate.

Comment: Thanks for you're response, I'm indeed using filter aggregation in Kibana data table to show counts of due/overdue/notdue and like you mentioned its performance is also very good, but its useful for counts only. I have to show in single String field with value `Due` or `Over Due` or `Not Due` in drill down(Saved Search Discover). So, it seems like scripted field is the only way, I implemented it now, I'll post it in the answer for the community.